# Share localhost mysql database with cloud computing instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

How can I copy the content of a specific table (or the table as is) from my local database to a database instance stored on a cloud, lets say Amazon RDS?
note: it has to be done ones every hour.

EDIT:
Other I/O operations on the local database should no be suspended (e.g. no READ LOCKS).

Comment: Is you local database accessible using your IP from anywhere on the internet ?

Comment: Yes, and for that matter, I'm also using DDNS service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your local database server to be a master to the Amazon RDS instance which means the Amazon RDS instance becomes a slave in this setup. This is possible to do as mentioned in the AWS documentation here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html

You can also configure the slave to update only a specific table in the database after a specified interval of time.